# Постоянно растёт лог-файл Laravel

Tags: laravel, логирование

Laravel 4.2 пишет логи непрерывно. Как результат laravel.log разрастается довольно быстро до 5Гб и далее. Конфигурацию ротации файла я не нашёл, по хорошему мне не нужны данные "за всегда", а только за последнюю неделю, к примеру.

Куда копать?

Comment: А логгер какой используете? Пример для monolog можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28325019/4041128)

Comment: Да, из коробки monolog. Как поковыряюсь отпишусь. Заранее спасибо, решение походу тут https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php в сорцах, в методе rotate

Comment: Если у Вас Linux, то воспользуйтесь стандартной утилитой [logrotate](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=logrotate)

Comment: Обязательно, ещё руки до задачи не дошли :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации этот момент освещен. **[Errors & Logging](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#configuration)**.

Откройте файл `app/start/global.php`.

Найдите там эту секцию:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Error Logger
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will configure the error logger setup for the application which
| is built on top of the wonderful Monolog library. By default we will
| build a basic log file setup which creates a single file for logs.
|
*/

Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
```

Замените

```
Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
```

На

```
Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log', 7);
```

Вторым параметром передаете количество дней, за которое нужно хранить логи.
1 день = 1 файл.

Вот документация по этому методу:

```
/**
 * Register a daily file log handler.
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param int $days
 * @param string $level
 * @return void 
 * @static 
 */
 public static function useDailyFiles($path, $days = 0, $level = 'debug'){
     \Illuminate\Log\Writer::useDailyFiles($path, $days, $level);
 }
```

Comment: Как это можно было не заметить вообще? Оо Спасибо большое. :)